# how to parse simple JSON file to get Country name

Tags: android

```
[
{
    "value": "America (America)",
    "id": "1898"
},
{
    "value": "Afghanistan",
    "id": "546"
},
{
    "value": "India",
    "id": "119"
},
{
    "value": "London",
    "id": "1884"
},
{
    "value": "Caneda",
    "id": "32"
},
{
    "value": "Australiya",
    "id": "1891"
},
```

Comment: this is not an XML, its a JSON string

Comment: That is Json not xml, confirm firt than post question

Comment: but in above file,it is write between -<string> and ,<string> Tag so...

Comment: what Web Service are you using ? Paste your exact response which you are parsing.

Comment: anybody please tell me the best example of json array parsing in android

Answer (score 2):

First create a class as model :

```
public class Country {
    String countryName;
    String countryValue;

    public String getCountryName() {
        return countryName;
    }

    public void setCountryName(String countryName) {
        this.countryName = countryName;
    }

    public String getCountryValue() {
        return countryValue;
    }

    public void setCountryValue(String countryValue) {
        this.countryValue = countryValue;
    }

}
```

And use like this in your code :

```
ArrayList<Country> mCountries = new ArrayList<Country>();
            try {
                JSONArray mJsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
                for (int i = 0; i < mJsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject mJsonObject = mJsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    Country mCountry = new Country();
                    mCountry.setCountryName(mJsonObject.getString("value"));
                    mCountry.setCountryValue(mJsonObject.getString("id"));
                    mCountries.add(mCountry);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using below code:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist= new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>(); 
JSONArray json = new JSONArray(result);

for(int i=0;i<json.length();i++){                        
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();    
    JSONObject obj = json.getJSONObject(i);

    map.put("value", obj.getString("value"));
    map.put("id", obj.getString("id"));
    mylist.add(map);            
}
```